# Writing shareable service in angular2

Tags: angular

In angular 1, I would create a service as below:

```
// dataCache service used as a cache
angular.module('foo').service('dataCache', function() {
  this.firstname;
  this.lastname;
});
```

Now I can inject this service into any number of controllers or other services and retain or reset values of firstname and lastname. 
dataCache is a shareable service.

I want to write something similar in Angular 2

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class dataCache {
  constructor(public firstname: string, public lastname: string) {
    }
}
```

Now when I inject this service, I get an error saying

```
Property 'fistname' does not exist on type 'dataCache'.
```

this is how it's being used

```
import {dataCache} from '<folder>/datacache.service';

@Page({
  template: ``,
  providers: [dataCache]
})
export class somePage {
  constructor(private data: dataCache) {}
}
```

Comment: Dunno if that is an exact error message but it looks like maybe you've got a typo in `fistname` vs `firstname`

Comment: This will not work because when you inject datacache service into your controller at that moment constructor runs and as per your code it requires to have firstname and last name which you don't pass anywhere. Try my code and then inject it, it will work for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class dataCache {

  //------------either--------------------

  public firstname: string="micronyks"; 
  public lastname: string="angular2";

 //------------End--------------------

 //-------------or----------------

  public firstname: string; 
  public lastname: string;

  constructor()
  {
        this.firstname="micronyks";
        this.lastname:"angular2";
  }
  //--------------End-----------------

}
```

in component.

```
export class app{
    constructor(private ss:dataCache){
            console.log(ss.firstname) //micronyks
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? once you inject your datacache service, `firstname` and `lastname` will be accessible. tell me your usecase. or show me how and where you use datacache service and how you inject it?

Comment: dataCache holds data that I need to share between different pages

Comment: .also included dataCache in providers annotation for app